# Create a single MeshCollider for mesh with many vertices

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am doing some calculation with meshes in unity and adding `MeshCollider`'s to calculate pathfinding. Some meshes that are generated are very big and splits meshes into 2 or more 'mesh parts'. I set MeshCollider like so:

```
testRoom = GameObject.Find("testroom");
MeshFilter[] _filters = testRoom.GetComponentsInChildren<MeshFilter>();
foreach (MeshFilter _filter in _filters)
{
   _verts.AddRange(_filter.mesh.vertices);
   _triangles.AddRange(_filter.mesh.triangles);

   testRoom.AddComponent<MeshCollider>();
   testRoom.GetComponent<MeshCollider>().sharedMesh = _filter.mesh;
}
```

This obviously dont work with several meshparts since the Collider gets overwritten. Since the mesh is to big I cannot merge the meshes together and set a collider, right? When I use the Generate Colliders box in unity it works fine but I want a programmable solution since I am to generate the meshes at runtime.

Does anyone know how to make a single collider for the big mesh that is split into several parts due to having to many vertices?

Here is a picture of the mesh (as requested) It might look abit strange but it's (part of) an office building. I made the mesh myself using a Tango tablet. I diddnt include a tango tag because I did not think how the mesh looked would affect the answer.

[image]

Comment: it is **inconceivable** you would use mesh colliders.  as a rule, you never use mesh colliders, ever, in game engineering.  (there are only one or two unusual uses for them.)

Comment: Could you elaborate on this please? I use them (it because there should only be one) because it was the easiest way to do the ray tracing I wanted in unity.

Comment: why do you mention that it's a "tango" tablet? I mean, I am now interested in one of those, but why? :)

Answer (score 1):

I dont fully understand your situation, to be honest, but if you need a collider that will cover complex object created from script you still can add it to each object separately at runtime, right? So instead of

```
testRoom.AddComponent<MeshCollider>();
testRoom.GetComponent<MeshCollider>().sharedMesh = _filter.mesh;
```

you can do

```
var collider = _filter.gameObject.AddComponent<MeshCollider>();
collider.sharedMesh = _filter.mesh;
```

You cant add more than one MeshFilter component to a gameObject anyway, so any filter you get from testRoom.GetComponentsInChildren() is attached to a different object. Therefore you can add new collider to each one of them individually.

Comment: I'm sorry I was not clear about my situation, not sure how to describe it more clear for you. The code you provided does add all MeshColliders which is really nice and I will use this untill I find a way to create a single one! I dont think I can mark this as 'correct answer' even though It works. If I can, please tell and I will!

Comment: It's up to you to decide if my answer is correct -) So you want to have one collider that will somehow cover all the meshes, right? I'm not sure if its even possible. If all the child objects with meshes are logically the one big object (and you`re ok with detecting them by your pathfinder as one object), then you can use CombineMeshes() method in order to group all of them in one and add a collider to it afterwards. I cant figure any other way except for combining them or using separate colliders.

Comment: Ok I see, then this would be the correct answer untill someone figures out a way. I dont think I can combine them since the reason they are separate in the first place is because the mesh was to big to fit.

Answer (score 0):

You can of course add the colliders at runtime as you are already doing. This will give you very heavy and poor performance solution that will work but slow. Normal practice in this case would be modelling lowpoly version of that mesh you will use as a collider.

Another solution if your objects aren't too complex would be box colliders. You would need to grab renderer.bounds 
http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Renderer-bounds.html
and create new box collider with that bounds
http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Collider-bounds.html

Hope that make sense

Comment: Makes alot of sense. Im not concerned with performance since only one mesh will have a collider and then that wont be changed in the program. The sad thing is, the mesh (that have 2 splitted submeshes due to being to big) were already a low poly mesh containing only a fraction of the original data so this is considered but I cannot simplify it anymore if I want the mesh to be usable. 

Box colliders only works with the outside of the mesh no? I need to check individual triangles in the mesh representing a room so I dont think that will be usable but I might be wrong.

Comment: Can you show us your mesh? would be much easier to find solution

Comment: Ok! I posted a picture of it, not sure if that is what you wanted or if you wanted the actual file but.. well.